# Comparable<> and compareTo method A-Z and Z-A

Tags: java, android, string, sorting, comparable

Is there a way how to sort `String` both ways A to Z and Z to A calling same `compareTo override method`?

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Historial o) {
        String a = this.getName();
        String b = o.getName();


        return a.compareTo(b);//This sorts A-Z
    }
```

Comment: Sort using `Comparator.naturalOrder().reversed()`.

Comment: @AndyTurner and for lower API level?

Comment: Write the comparator yourself; it's really not hard: `public int compare(T a, T b) { return b.compareTo(a); }`.

Answer (score 0):

just replace the names of variables its easy

```
return a.compareTo(b);//This sorts A-Z
return b.compareTo(a);//This sorts Z-A
```